# Type class pattern for unary type constructors

Tags: scala, typeclass, higher-kinded-types

Given the following type class definition:

```
trait AttributeParser[T] {
  def parse(attribute: String): T
}
```

I am able to create implementations for nullary type constructors of kind `*` (think `Int`, `String`, `Boolean`, etc):

```
implicit object IntAttributeParser extends AttributeParser[Int] {
  override def parse(attribute: String): Int = ???
}
```

I would also like to implement these parsers for unary type constructors of kind `* -> *` (think `List[T]`, `Option[T]`, etc), but the current definition fails for obvious reasons:

```
implicit object OptionAttributeParser extends AttributeParser[Option]
```

Gives:

> class `Option` takes type parameters

Since we need to specify `Option[T]`, but that isn't possible since `AttributeParser` is defined by `T`, not `T[_]`.

One possible solution would be to define a type alias for each `Option[T]` type, for example:

```
type OptionInt = Option[Int]
```

And then the compiler is happy:

```
implicit object OptionIntParser extends AttributeParser[OptionInt] {
  override def parse(node: Node, attribute: String): OptionInt = ???
}
```

But that would force me to create a type alias instead of generically defining a solution for all `Option[T]`.

Is there any solution which would allow to pass both kinds of type `*` and `* -> *` to the type class definition?

---

### Edit

My initial assumption that `AttributeParser[T]` is of kind * for nullary type constructors was of course wrong. An `AttributeParser[Int]` is still a type constructor of kind `* -> *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a reason why the compiler would reject your higher kind `Option[_]`:

```
implicit object OptionAttributeParser extends AttributeParser[Option[_]] { ... }
```

It changes the type constructor from `* -> *` to `(* -> *) -> *`, yes, but compiler will see both cases as "some type in, some type out". Just like you can specify e.g. `Option[Set[_]]`.

Note that `Option[_]` will not suffice when you get to implementation of your `OptionAttributeParser`:

```
implicit object OptionAttributeParser extends AttributeParser[Option[_]] {
  override def parse(attribute: String): Option[_] = ???
}

def foo[A : AttributeParser](p: A) = p

foo(Option(42))
```

> could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type
>   `AttributeParser[Option[Int]]`

But that can be easily fixed:

```
implicit def optionAttributeParser[T] = new AttributeParser[Option[T]] {
  override def parse(attribute: String): Option[T] = ???
}

def foo[A : AttributeParser](p: A) = p

foo(Option(42)) // Some(42)
```

Comment: I want to keep type `T`, if I work with `Option[_]` I lose the underlying type.

Comment: That's exactly the solution I went with. I was waiting to see if you'd come up with it ;)

Comment: Haha :) and the funniest part is that I didn't edit my answer based on your comment, because I only saw it later when I was done with it.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is polymorphic instance via `def` which could look like this:

```
implicit def optionAttributeParser[T](implicit parser: AttributeParser[T]) =
  new AttributeParser[Option[T]] {
    def parse(attribute: String): Option[T] =
      if (attribute.isEmpty) None else Some(parser.parse(attribute))
  }
```

Sometimes more generic pattern is used for higher kinds like [`cats.MonoidK`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/MonoidK.scala).
 In your case you could define higher-kinded typeclass

```
trait AttributeParserK[F[_]] {
  def parseK[T](attribute: String)(implicit itemParser: AttributeParser[T]): F[T]
}
```

and include some additional instance in your instances scope

```
object AttributeParser{
  implicit def kindParser[F[_], T](implicit itemParser: AttributeParser[T], parserK: AttributeParserK[F]) =
    new AttributeParser[F[T]] {
      def parse(attribute: String): F[T] = parserK.parseK(attribute)
    }
}
```

Comment: Which implicit type class would I require for the calling `parse`? Would it still be `AttributeParser[T]`? If so, how would it differentiate between the monomorphic case with kind `*` with the higher kind `* -> *`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov generally you will only work with simple `Parser`, which instance would be automatically provided for your `Option`s, `List`s, etc. `ParserK` is more sensible way to define instances for higher kinds and rarely will be summoned directly.

Comment: As an API writer, how would you know when to summon `ParserK` indirectly? Since, for example, an `Int` and `Option[Int]` don't share the common parser `Parser[F]`, since they are `AttributeParser[F]` and `AttributeParser[F[_], T]` respectively.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov You can see that in my example `ParserK` requires `Parser` for successfull call, so `ParserK` is no more than way to convert `Parser[A]` to `Parser[F[A]]` and you will expect that `Parser[Option[A]]` will use the same underlying  instance of `Parser[A]` as code using it directly in the same context.

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you mean now. I'll try implementing it using `MonoidK` to get the hang of it, thank you.

Comment: Actually in cats `MonoidK[Option]` can give you a `Monoid[Option[A]]` without a `Monoid[A]` by using `None` as the empty element and `Option#orElse` as the combine operation.

Comment: @PeterNeyens definitely, it was just looking like nonsense to do it the same way here.